# Inverse Laplace Tranform of a function involving Bessel functions

Tags: bessel-functions, inverse-laplace

I need to evaluate (if it exists) the inverse Laplace transform of the following complex function $F(s)$:
$$
F(s)=\sqrt{\frac{s}{a}} J_{1}(\sqrt{as})
$$
where $J_{1}(\cdot)$ is the Bessel function of first kind and first order.

Does anyone have any suggestion?

I know that an inverse Laplace transform exists for a similar expression, i.e., 
$$
L \left\{ \frac{1}{4t^2 } e^{-\frac{a}{4t}} \right\} = \sqrt{\frac{s}{a}} K_{1}(\sqrt{as})
$$
where $K_{1}(\cdot)$ is the modified Bessel function of second kind and first order.

Thanks!

Comment: Write the series expansion of $J_1$.

Comment: But in this case I would obtain a series of distributions, wouldn't I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're struggling with Voronoi's improvement of the Gauss circle problem.
If you're interested, I am writing a section about it in [my notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view), it is not finished yet but it will probably be before the new year (2019).
Anyway, you may consider Bessel's differential equation defining $J_1$, or directly the Maclaurin series of $J_1$, and discover that

$$\color{red}{\mathcal{L}}\left(\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n a^{n} (s)^{n+1}}{ 2^{2n+1} n!(n+1)!}\right) = \frac{1}{2x^2} e^{-\frac{a}{4x}}$$
but the series is associated to an entire function, so its *inverse* Laplace transform is simply not defined, unless you're fine with a distributional identity $\mathcal{L}^{-1}(s^n)(x)=\delta^{(n)}(x)$.

Comment: For some reasons, I would need to express the propagator (advanced, retarted, or Feynmann propagator) as a Laplace transform of some quantity.

Comment: And unfortunately the expression of the sought inverse Laplace transform as a series of distributions is not useful for my purposes. I need a closed form expression to be further manipulated. In any case, I also wonder if such an inverse Laplace transform exists in the sense of functions...

Comment: @MrCastozzo: the answer is *no* by Hamburger's theorem: the oscillations of $J_1$ violate log-convexity, so your expression cannot be the Laplace transform of a function defined on $\mathbb{R}^+$. On the other hand you already have your $\mathcal{L}^{-1}$: if it is a distribution and not a function, it is a distribution and not a function.

Comment: Dear Jack, thanks for your answer and explanation.